# Weird error while compiling C

Tags: c, list, compilation, linked-list

So I have been on this for quite some time now and can't seem to find the problem, not even my teacher could find it.

So I have this header file:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    void print_list(void);
    int delete_from_list(int iWordID);
    wordData * create_list(int iWordID, char * cWord);
    wordData * add_to_list(int iWordID, char * cWord, bool add_to_end);
    wordData * search_in_list(int iWordID, struct wordData **prev);
    void print_list(void);

    typedef struct _wordData
    {
    int iWordID;
    char * cWord;
    struct _wordData *next;

    } wordData;
```

And in the C file where I include this header I have this function:

```
    wordData* create_list(int iWordID, char * cWord)
    {
     //printf(cWord);

    printf("\n creating list with headnode as [%d] %s\n",iWordID,cWord);
    wordData *ptr = (struct wordData*)malloc(sizeof(struct wordData));
    if(NULL == ptr)
    {
    printf("\n Node creation failed \n");
    return NULL;
    }

    ptr->iWordID = iWordID;

    //char * temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(cWord));
    ptr -> cWord = cWord;


    ptr->next = NULL;

    head = curr = ptr;
    return ptr;
    }
```

So when I compile this error occurs:
list.h|6|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '*' token|

I have searched quite some awnsers on this error but can't seem to find one that helps me out.

Please help :)

Comment: Reminds me of my teacher lol

Comment: haha i know, thnx to Michael burr. I am used to OO programming where this is nog necessary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Move the `wordData` `struct` definition to the top fo the header - it needs to come before you use it in prototypes (or you need to forward declare it).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct _wordData
{
int iWordID;
char * cWord;
struct _wordData *next;

} wordData;

void print_list(void);
int delete_from_list(int iWordID);
wordData * create_list(int iWordID, char * cWord);
wordData * add_to_list(int iWordID, char * cWord, bool add_to_end);
wordData * search_in_list(int iWordID, struct wordData **prev);
void print_list(void);
```

Comment: (This is just a reshuffling of the components in your header file)

Comment: @flexzican: This is not all though. Even though the compiler might not complain at first, you still have a reference to non-existing type `struct wordData` in `search_in_list` declaration. Your type is called `struct _wordData` or simply `wordData`, but there's no such thing as `struct wordData`. Notice the difference? The same error is then repeated in the implementation file.

Answer (score 8):

Move the struct definition above where it's used in the header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct _wordData
{
int iWordID;
char * cWord;
struct _wordData *next;

} wordData;

void print_list(void);
int delete_from_list(int iWordID);
wordData * create_list(int iWordID, char * cWord);
wordData * add_to_list(int iWordID, char * cWord, bool add_to_end);
wordData * search_in_list(int iWordID, struct wordData **prev);
void print_list(void);
```

You have to define it before it's used.

```
wordData * search_in_list(int iWordID, struct wordData **prev);
                                             ^
                                             |
                             This is also incorrect. Should be "wordData **prev"
                              That's what the typedef is for.
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from moving the definition of structure before the point where you are using there is another change you need:

You've typedefed `struct _wordData` to `wordData`.

So you either use `struct _wordData` or `wordData`, but you are using `struct wordData` which does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

There are two independent errors in your code.

Firstly, typedef-name `wordData` has to be defined *before* it is used.

Secondly, in `search_in_list` declaration you refer to `struct wordData` type. There's no such type as `struct wordData` in your program at all. You have `struct _wordData` instead. The second error is then repeated in C file (in `malloc` etc.).